# continuous function definition equivalent

Tags: general-topology

The following is from wikipedia.
[image]

So I should take it if $f$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}(\text{cl}(B))$ contains $\text{cl}(f^{-1}(b))$?

What if I take 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}2&x<0\\3&x>0\end{cases}.$$
Then apparently this inclusion doesn't hold, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What set $B$ do you have a problem with? Note that you have to take closures in $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ (since $f$ doesn't have a continuous extension to $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: $f$ isn't continuous, why should the inclusion hold?

Comment: haha! that's true  Olivier!

Answer (score 2):

There are many  equivalents to "Inverses of open sets are open". Some are more useful than others in some contexts. Among them are:

1. Inverses of closed sets are closed.
2. If $A\subset dom(f)$ then $f(\overline A)\subset \overline {f(A)}.$

For a function between metric spaces, 2. is equivalent to: If $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is a sequence in $dom(f)$ which converges to  $x\in dom(f)$ then $(f(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converges to $f(x).$

3(a). For any $x\in dom(f)$ and any nbhd $V$ of $f(x)$  there is a nbhd $U$ of $x$ with $f(U)\subset V$.

3(b). For any $x\in dom(f)$ and open $V'$ containing $f(x)$ there is an open $U'$ containing $x$ with $f(U')\subset V'.$

.....$U$ is a nbhd of $x$ iff there is an open $U'$ with $x\in U'\subset U$..... 3(a) and 3(b) are generalizations of the "$\epsilon$-$\delta$ " form.

4. For every $x\in dom(f)$ there is a nbhd $U$ of $x$ or an open $U$' with $x\in U'$ such that $f|_U$ or $f|_{U'}$ ( the restriction of $f$ to the domain $U$ or $U'$ ) is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed as the entry on Wikipedia claims (in slightly different notation), the following two statements about a function $f: X \to Y$, where $X$ has some closure operator $\operatorname{cl}_X$ and $Y$ a closure operator $\operatorname{cl}_Y$ (as an alternative way to define the topology, in this case), are equivalent:

1. $\forall A \subseteq X: f[\operatorname{cl}_X(A)]) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}_Y(f[A])$.
2. $\forall B \subseteq Y: f^{-1}[\operatorname{cl}_Y(B)] \supseteq \operatorname{cl}_X(f^{-1}[B])$.

**Proof** assume 1. holds and let $B \subseteq Y$. Then first applying 1. with $A=f^{-1}[B]$ we get: $$f[\operatorname{cl}_X(f^{-1}[B]) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}_Y(f[f^{-1}[B]]) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}_Y(B)$$

where the last inclusion follows as $f[f^{-1}[B]] \subseteq B$ by definition and closure preserves inclusion.

And $f[\operatorname{cl}_X(f^{-1}[B]) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}_Y(B)$ implies 
$\operatorname{cl}_X(f^{-1}[B]) \subseteq f^{-1}[\operatorname{cl}_Y(B)]$ by the definition of inverse images, which shows that indeed 2. holds.

Assume now that 2. holds and let $A \subseteq X$. Then $A \subseteq f^{-1}[f[A]]$ and as closures and images preserve inclusions:

$$f[\operatorname{cl}_X(A)] \subseteq f[\operatorname{cl}(f^{-1}[f[A]])$$

to which we apply (2) with $B=f[A]$ to get:

$$f[\operatorname{cl}_X(A)] \subseteq f[f^{-1}[\operatorname{cl}_Y(f[A])]] \subseteq \operatorname{cl}_Y(f[A])$$

where the last inclusion is from $f[f^{-1}[C]] \subseteq C$ applied to $C=f[A]$.
So 1. has then been shown from 2.

In fact both these equivalent statements are also equivalent to the traditional definition of continuity as "$f^{-1}[O]$ is open for all open $O \subseteq Y$", or that statement with closed instead of open etc. This is a nice exercise to show.

But equivalence 1. makes it more immediate that the image of a dense set is dense e.g. and moreover, these definitions can be applied to a wider setting, like closure spaces instead of topological spaces, so they're useful in that sense too. It also captures the intuition that a continuous function sends something that is close to a set to a pount close to its image (so it doesn't "rip stuff apart").

The first issue with your example function is that it is not a function defined on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$, so let's define $f(0)=2$ to make it everywhere defined. It's clearly discontinuous (as a map from the reals to the reals in the usual topology on both sides) and 1. or 2. can be applied to see that: Take $A= (0,+\infty)$ then $f[\operatorname{cl}_X(A)] = f[[0,+\infty)] = \{2,3\}$ while 
$\operatorname{cl}_Y(f[A])= \operatorname{cl}_Y(\{3\})= \{3\}$ and 1. fails for this particular $A$.

Or take $B=\{3\}$ for 2: $f^{-1}[B]=(0,+\infty)$ which has closure $[0,+\infty)$ in $X$ while $f^{-1}[\operatorname{cl}_Y(B)] = f^{-1}[\{3\}]=(0,+\infty)$ is not a superset of it.

On the domain $X=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, $f$ **is** continuous and both statements do hold for all subsets (try this; remember to take the closure on $X$ in a smaller subset).

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\begin{cases}2&x<0\\3&x>0\end{cases}$
is continuous when the domain of f is R - {0}.

$f^{-1}(\text{cl}(B))$ contains $\text{cl}(f^{-1}(b))$
however is false.  For example B = {2}, b = 3.
As f does not have an inverse $f^{-1}(b)$ is devoid of meaning.
Same if b = 2 or any other element of the codomain which can be as large as R.

In the event you intended the false statement
$f^{-1}(\text{cl}(B))$ contains $\text{cl}(f^{-1}(B))$,
B = {2} is a counter example when the codomain of f is R.

What are the possible codomains for f for which that statement is true?